# Optimizing sql query to clickhouse database with large array in IN block

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a system that works with large amounts of data in clickhouse. When filtering values on the frontend part to select data through select, I get a back request like

```
SELECT
    param1,
    param2,
    ...,
    paramN
FROM
    table1 l ALL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id1,
        id2
    FROM
        table2)
        USING (id1)
WHERE
    any_parameter IN (value1, value2, value3, ... valueN)
ORDER BY
    another_param1 DESC,
    id1
LIMIT 0,25
```

So, inside IN there can be a huge enumeration, starting from 2500 values. Plus, one more of the same can be attached through AND. How can the IN block be optimized? Tried with temporary tables - not the best option, quickly littered with temporary tables. They also suggest on the Internet that it is necessary to split into subqueries or use NOT IN in order to pass those values that are excluded in the filter on the frontend. As a result, it is necessary to reduce the execution time of such requests.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to optimise large list or values in the IN operator is to use a temporary table with a primary key...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T (ID INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES 
(value1), 
(value2), 
(value3),
...
(valueN);

ALTER TABLE T ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

SELECT param1,
       param2,
       ...,
       paramN
FROM   table1 l ALL
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id1, id2
                        FROM   table2)
          USING (id1)
WHERE  any_parameter IN (SELECT ID FROM T)
ORDER  BY another_param1 DESC, id1
       LIMIT  0,25
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it. But the problem is that the values in the IN block are different each time, because they are formed on the basis of a List of values from the frontend part

Answer (score 0):

2500 values is usually nothing. check `explain plan` for your query - likely you'll see that the filter wasn't pushed down the join step. then you could do it manually.